# Permissions and Features

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need to build a app with some specific details, and since I never worked with Instagram I have no idea if is possible or not, and also the information that I find on the docs doesn't say much, so hope someone had the same experience.

So basically I need to track some analytic information, for example in my App, for someone to register it needs to login in Instagram and than must follow my Instagram page, I believe this is possible, but then I need to track some information from the users and that is:

- Check if the user is hashtaging my company page (to check which users made more shares or something);
- Check which users had more engagement;

Can someone tell me if this is possible to track on Instagram API?

Answer (score 0):

The new Instagram graph API is very limited, you cannot make to app and allow user to follow, you cannot access other user posts to check if they hashtagged or engaged.

All you can do is, access only your posts (if business account), and you can access your post's comments. You can also get last 24hrs of an hashtag, but no user info is given.

Comment: Though IG api shows a way to post comments on the post, but I think its not possible yet, can you confirm?

Comment: Is there a way for example force a user follow my page ? For example using instagram login or something?

Comment: @AnujKumar You can post comments on your posts with graph API

Comment: @Pedro not possible to have a user follow you via API